# Linq неправильно сортирует

Tags: c#, linq

Необходимо отобрать наиболее часто встречающиеся цифры. Если таких цифр несколько -  вывести тут которая обозначает наибольшее число.

Проблема такая: если повторяющийся цифр несколько, он выдаёт те, которые находятся ближе к левому краю.

```
        int[] a = { 1,1,1,2,2,2};
        var most = a
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Наиболее часто встречается {0} в количестве {1}", most.Key, most.Count());
```

Comment: Так вы ведь сами указали First or default(то что первее или по-умолчанию). 1 первее, поэтому и получается 1

Comment: Max() выкидывает исключение, не пойму как сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная идея алгоритма, в том чтобы количество имело приемущество перед значением (как десятки перед единицами)

- для того чтобы количество измерялось в 10 ках мы умножаем на 10,
- значение делим на максимальное таким образом получаем погрешность
  не больше 1.

например для {10, 10, 2, 2, 2}:

- `2` * 10 + `10` / 10 для десятки = `21`;
- `3` * 10 + `2` / 10 для двойки = `30.2`

в данном случае для приведения числа к диапазону от 0 до 1 используется формула:

```
 ((число-min) / (max-min))
```

код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

const int countItems = 1000001;

List<int> a = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < countItems; i++)
    a.Add(0);
for (int i = 0; i < countItems + 1; i++)
    a.Add(0);

int countWeight = a.Count() / 2 + 1;
int max = a.Max();
int min = a.Min();

if (max != min){ // избегаем деления на ноль
    IGrouping<int, int> most =
       a.GroupBy(n => n)
        .OrderByDescending(
          (n) => n.Count() * countWeight + ((n.Sum()-min) / (max-min))
        )
        .First();
    Console.WriteLine("Наиболее часто встречается {0} в количестве {1}", most.Key, most.Count());
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Наиболее часто встречается {0} в количестве {1}", min, a.Count());
}
```

В качестве дополнения темы я попробовал реализовать этот алгоритм в `чистом виде` на js
выполнив снипет можно посмотреть как вычисляются веса использовано 3 варианта расчета.

```js
const find = (numA, numB, numC, countA, countB, countC, formulaCountWeight) => {
  let weightA = 0;
  let weightB = 0;
  let weightC = 'отсутствует';

  let a = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < countA; i++)
      a.push(numA);
  for (let i = 0; i < countB; i++)
      a.push(numB);
  for (let i = 0; i < countC; i++)
      a.push(numC);

  const countWeight = [
    1 / a.length / 2  + 1,
    a.length / 2  + 1,
    10
  ][formulaCountWeight];

  // const max = Math.max.apply(null,a);
  // const min = Math.min.apply(null, a);
  // не справлялись на больших числах
  const {max, min} = a.reduce((acc, e) => (
    {
      max: acc.max < e ? e: acc.max,
      min: acc.min > e ? e: acc.min,
    }
  ), {max: -Infinity, min: Infinity})

  if (max != min){
    let res = {}
    // подсчет количества
    res = a.reduce((acc, e) =>  (
       {...acc, [e] : acc[e] ? {count: acc[e].count + 1} : {count: 1} }
    ),  {})
    // вычисление веса
    res = Object.keys(res)
      .map(n => (
        { 
          weight : res[n].count * countWeight + ((+n-min) / (max-min)),
          num: n,
          count: res[n].count
        }))  
    weightA = res[0].weight;
    weightB = res[1].weight;
    if (res[2]) weightC = res[2].weight;
    // сотрировка по убыванию веса  
    res.sort((a, b) => b.weight - a.weight) 
    resultNum = res[0].num;
    resultCount = res[0].count; 
  } else {
    resultNum = min;
    resultCount = countA + countB; 
  }
  return { weightA, weightB, weightC, resultNum, resultCount }
}

  const form = document.querySelector("form");
  form.onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const { weightA, weightB, weightC, resultNum, resultCount } = 
    find( 
      +document.querySelector("[name=a]").value,    
      +document.querySelector("[name=b]").value,
      +document.querySelector("[name=c]").value,        
      +document.querySelector("[name=cnt_a]").value,    
      +document.querySelector("[name=cnt_b]").value,
      +document.querySelector("[name=cnt_c]").value,
      +document.querySelector("[name=formula_countWeight]").value,
      
    )
    document.querySelector('#weight_a').textContent = weightA;
    document.querySelector('#weight_b').textContent = weightB;
    document.querySelector('#weight_c').textContent = weightC;
    document.querySelector('#num').textContent = resultNum;
    document.querySelector('#count').textContent = resultCount; 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    span { font-weight: bold; }
    div  { display: flex; margin: 5px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>число a:<input type="number" value="1" name="a"></label>
      <label>&nbspв количестве:<input type="number" value="1000002" name="cnt_a"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>число b:<input type="number" value="0" name="b"></label>
      <label>&nbspв количестве:<input type="number" value="1000002" name="cnt_b"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>число с:<input type="number" value="2" name="c"></label>
      <label>&nbspв количестве: <input type="number" value="1000002" name="cnt_c"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        формула веса
        <select name="formula_countWeight">
          <option value="0" selected="selected" >= 1 / length / 2  + 1</option>
          <option value="1" >= length / 2  + 1</option>
          <option value="2" >= 10</option>
        <select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Найти</button>
  <form>
  <p>веса: а=<span id="weight_a"></span> b=<span id="weight_b"></span> c=<span id="weight_c"></span></p>
  <p>результат: число <span id="num"></span> в количестве: <span id="count"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120994/discussion-on-answer-by-daniil-loban-linq--).

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуемся тем, что кортежи сортируются лексикографически. То есть при сравнении кортежей если первая компонента одинакова, то сравнивается вторая и т. д.

Посчитаем кортежи из количества одинаковых значений и самих значений, тогда наибольшее значение кортежа будет как раз тем, что нам нужно: будет сравниваться сначала количество, а при равенстве количеств — сами значения.

Получаем такой код:

```cs
int[] a = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
var best = a.GroupBy(n => n).Select(g => (count: g.Count(), value: g.Key)).Max();
Console.WriteLine($"Наиболее часто встречается {best.value} в количестве {best.count}");
```

Выводит:

> Наиболее часто встречается 2 в количестве 3

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ЕвгенийВерютин: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Интересно, как оно Max для тапла считает...

Comment: @aepot: Лексикографически, написал в первом же предложении. :)

Comment: @VladD а, читать надо было? :) вижу